# FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures. 1: Task failed with an exception

Tags: android-studio

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\New folder\Candy Crush\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s